# Can I mark an elastic search index as incomplete? Can I retrieve the list of "complete" indices?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I want to populate an index but make it searchable only after I'm done. Is there a standard way of doing that with elastic search? I think I can set `"index.blocks.read": true` but I'd like a way to be able to ask elastic for a list of the searchable indices and I don't know how to do that with that setting. Also closing/opening an index feels a bit cumbersome.

A solution I found is to add a document to each index defining that index's status. Though querying for the list of indices is a bit annoying. Specifically since querying and paginating a long list of 2,000 index status documents is problematic. Scroll-scan is a solution because it gives me all the results in one go (because every shard has at most 1 index status document). Though that feels like I'm using the wrong tool for the job (i.e. a scroll-scan op that always does exactly one scroll).

I don't want one document that references all the indices because then I'd have to garbage collect it manually alongside garbage collecting indices. But maybe that's the best tradeoff...

Is there a standard practice that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using aliases? Instead of querying an index directly, your application could query an alias (e.g. `live`) instead. As long as your index is not ready (i.e. still being populated), you don't assign the `live` alias to it and hence the index won't be searchable.

Basically, the process goes like this:

1. Create the index with its settings and mappings
2. Populate it
3. When done, [assign the `live` alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) to it and send your queries against it
4. Later when you need to index new data, you create another index
5. You populate that new index
6. When done, you [switch the aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html), i.e. remove the `live` alias from the previous searchable index and assign the `live` alias to the new searchable index

Here is [a simple example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) that demonstrates this.

Comment: I believe that's a great solution. Thank you!